# Execute Database Write and Read tasks in Sequence on Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using the `beam-nuggets` library to read and write data to a Postgres database from an Apache Beam pipeline. I want to execute the following two tasks in sequence:

1. Insert a new row into a `processing_info` table.
2. Query for the primary key of the newly created `processing_info` table record. The value of primary key query will then be passed to another `DoFn` as a side input (wherein it is used to populate a foreign key column of a related table).

Currently, I am creating the `processing_info` record before I execute the Beam pipeline, but I would like to create the new record as part of the pipeline execution (it makes things simpler when running the pipeline on Google Dataflow). The code would ideally look something like this:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    # Executes first
    proc_id_result = (p | 'Create Proc Info Record' >> beam.Create([{'pipeline_name': 'cleansed_data_pipeline'}])
                          | 'Make Processing Id' >> relational_db.Write(
                                source_config=source_config,
                                table_config=proc_table_config))
    # Executes second
    proc_id_record = p | relational_db.ReadFromDB(
            source_config=source_config,
            table_name='processing_info',
            query='SELECT pi.id FROM processing_info pi WHERE processing_date_time = '
                  '   (SELECT MAX(pi1.processing_date_time) from processing_info pi1 '
                  f'      where pi1.pipeline_name = \'cleansed_data_pipeline\')'
        )
    ...
    # This code executes later, and is automatically deferred until the side input is available
    | 'Add \'processing_info_id\'' >>
                (beam.ParDo(AddKeyValuePairToDict(), 'processing_info_id', AsSingleton(proc_id_record)))
    ...
```

I might be able to hack something in (e.g. an unused side input) to defer the query until the Insert operation has completed, but I wanted to know if there is a more idiomatic approach (I'm new to Beam).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You hit the right idea: You can do this with an unused side input. You'd do something like this (which is used in Beam itself for ReadFromBigQuery

```py
class PassThrough(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    yield element

output = input | beam.ParDo(PassThrough()).with_outputs(
    'cleanup_signal', main='main')
main_output = output['main']
cleanup_signal = output['cleanup_signal']

single_element = (
    input.pipeline
    | beam.Create([None])
    | beam.Map(lambda x, nothing: x, beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(cleanup_signal)))

single_element | relational_db.ReadFromDB(...)
```

Now, the issue is making this work with your `ReadFromDB` transform, which I guess doesn't take an input like this. Is there a way to do it for that transform?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Pablo. I am able to extend the ReadFromDB transform and use a side input in the __init__ method of the subclass. Not sure if there is a better way, but it works.